# Why is the coadjoint orbit passing through $X$ determined by the spectrum of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G=SO(n,R)$ be a Lie group and $\mathbb{g}$ its lie algebra. Take $X\in \mathbb{g}$.

Then why is the coadjoint orbit passing through $X$ determined by the spectrum of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by spectrum of $X$ you mean it's eigenvalues?  Also, you talk about coadjoint orbit but $X \in \mathfrak g$.  This is really not a problem since $G$ has an $Ad$-invariant inner product so that the induced identification of $\mathfrak g \simeq \mathfrak g^*$ preserves the adjoint action.

Anyways, any adjoint orbit of a semisimple group passes through any maximal torus.  Choose the usual maximal torus of $\mathfrak{so(n)}$ consisting of block $2\times 2$ skew-symmetric matrices.  The eigenvalues of such a matrix are the eigenvalues of the blocks.  Since the Weyl group acts by permuting these blocks, elements with the same eigenvalues are in the same adjoint orbit.